In a C# / .NET Core web application, is it alright to use controller actions without a default value for CancellationToken?
I often find the below CancellationToken patterns withing .NET Core web application controllers (sometimes both within the same one). I would prefer using a single one for consistency.
Is there a difference when using either of these?
Pattern #1 , ct = default
[Route("my-controller")]
[ApiController]
public class MyController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost("search")]
    public async Task<MyData[]> ByQuery([FromBody] query, CancellationToken ct = default)
    { 
       // ...
    }
}

Pattern #2 no default:
[HttpPost("search")]
public async Task<MyData[]> ByQuery([FromBody] query, CancellationToken ct)
{ 
    // ...
}

Both patterns seem to work as expected.

IMHO, that's not relevant, because it's an internal affair. When the handler resolver finds a CancellationToken argument, should provide a copy from its own source. Thus, giving a default won't change your behavior. By other means, I stopped using the CT in the API handlers because that will raise a lot of cancellations during the normal web usage. Do I really need to cancel everything?

Pretty sure the default IActionInvoker will provide the same CancellationToken in both cases. Do you have any test cases that call the method directly?

@MarioVernari It is good to have a way to prevent users that refresh a lot their browsers impacting the app performanace. Maybe you should handle the CT exception errors with a simple filter like the one suggested here

The slight point is here, who creates the CancellationToken for the actions?
The answer is webserver which is Kestrel by default, when it wants to instantiate the HttpContext.
No matter where you call the API, from a Browser or Postman, the CancellationToken will be created by Kestrel, and it makes sense because when you refresh the browser or close it, the webserver is the first one that notifies request disconnection and will fire the CancellationToken.
So to answer your question, both scenarios will have the same CancellationToken.
I prefer to use HttpContext.RequestAborted and no need to inject CancelltionToken in every Action and your code will be more clean:
[HttpPost("search")]
public async Task<MyData[]> ByQuery([FromBody] query)
{ 
   await SomeAsync(query, HttpContext.RequestAborted)
   //...
}


At runtime, the ASP.NET Core framework uses model binding to provide a value for CancellationToken, regardless of the default parameter.
The CancellationToken ct = default is essentially the same as CancellationToken ct = CancellationToken.None which will have its CanBeCanceled property aways return false.
Here is a simple demo, you can also put in a break point to see the cancellationToken.CanBeCanceled returns true in both cases:
    [HttpGet("/default")]
    public ActionResult Default(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        if (cancellationToken != CancellationToken.None)
        {
            return Ok("Token is not the default");
        }

        return Ok("Token is the default");
    }

    [HttpGet("/no-default")]
    public ActionResult NoDefault(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (cancellationToken == HttpContext.RequestAborted)
        {
            return Ok("same as HttpContext.RequestAborted");
        }

        return Ok();
    }

